# Fix an import error and TypeError: ActiveDirectory is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, active-directory

I want to use active directory in a Vue.js web app but once the module is install, I try to run my app several errors appears...

After installing the module: npm install activedirectory --save 
I do have a form with login/password, and while I submit, activedirectory module is launched:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require("activedirectory");
var config = {
host: "147.156.182.39",
port: "452",
baseDN: "dc=juice,dc=fr",
username: "anfinsol_save@juice.fr",
password: "password123"
};
```

Errors while first click: 
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: unknown stream type "undefined""

found in

```
---> <AthentComponent> at src/components/subcomponents/AuthentComponent.vue
<MainPage> at src/views/Accueil.vue
<App> at src/App.vue
<Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
VueJS 7
TypeError: "unknown stream type "undefined""
addStream bunyan.js:620
Logger bunyan.js:470
Logger bunyan.js:469
createLogger bunyan.js:1618
<anonymous> activedirectory.js:16
<anonymous> activedirectory.js:1901
js app.js:925
__webpack_require__ app.js:767
fn app.js:130
<anonymous> index.js:1
js app.js:914
__webpack_require__ app.js:767
fn app.js:130
submit AuthentComponent.vue:52
```

Second click error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: ActiveDirectory is not a constructor"

found in

---> <AthentComponent> at src/components/subcomponents/AuthentComponent.vue
<MainPage> at src/views/Accueil.vue
<App> at src/App.vue
<Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
TypeError: "ActiveDirectory is not a constructor"
submit AuthentComponent.vue:57
VueJS 3
```

Use activedirectory properly with no errors, I already tryed several versions and uninstall/install the module but still not working.

Comment: Could you show the content of the file `AuthentComponent.vue`?

Comment: <script> import LanguageComponent from "@/components/LanguageComponent"; import EventBus from "@/helpers/EventBus"; export default { name: "AthentComponent", components: { LanguageComponent }, data() { return { login: null, password: null }; }, methods: { submit() { var ActiveDirectory = require("activedirectory"); var config = { host: "147.156.182.39", port: "452", baseDN: "dc=juice,dc=fr", username: "anfinsol_save@juice.fr", password: "password123" };var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);}} </script>